# Model.List is null on POST using Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My view:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.List)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.UserId)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Name)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.Age)

  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.IsChecked, new { id = item.UserId })
  <label>@item.Name</label>
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyModel Model)
{
..
```

`Model.List` is null?

The list populates okay on `GET`. However, on `POST` (this particular View is a form) `Model.List` is null. I've tried using the `HiddenFor` helper, but have not yet succeeded.

Any suggestions / answers are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your controller code

Comment: Show us your code in controller

Comment: I've updated my post. I've only shown a segment as (I think) the rest of the code is irrelevant? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass list objects with MVC Razor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552931/pass-list-objects-with-mvc-razor)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop for data binding to work correctly with collections.

So instead of doing a foreach loop, change your code to something like this:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.List.Count(); i++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.List[i].UserId)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.List[i].Name)
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.List[i].Age)

  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.List[i].IsChecked, new { id = Model.List[i].UserId })
  <label>@Model.List[i].Name</label>
}
```

This enables the ModelBinder to track the index of the item in your collection you're trying to bind.

If you look at the generated HTML when you have done this, you will notice that the generated input controls will look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="List[0].IsChecked" />
```

This enables the model binder to know to which item in the list, it is binding to.

Comment: also just wanted to say thanks. I also have a follow up question btw. Do you if there is a way to implement this but instead of having the form inputs nested directly within the for loop, i pass a partial view which receives a model of the List<type> object. I have been looking for a solution but cannot seem to find one.