# Unable to pass list to controller with data table. ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatables

I have a cshtml page that will be sending a list of items over to my controller. However when i click on the submit button, nothing is being passed over to my controller.

The codes below is my cshtml codes which will pass the model over to my controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-group">
        @if (Model.Count() != 0)
        {
        <input type='button' value='Save and Update' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
        }
    </div>
    <table class="table cell-border" id="TempTable5">
        <tbody>
            @if (Model.Count() != 0)
            {
                int j = 0;
                foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ExerciseInstruction.ExerciseInstructionID)
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ExerciseInstruction.ExerciseInstructionID)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Exercise.Name)
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <iframe width="300" height="175" src=@item.ExerciseVideo.VideoURL frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Therapist.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ExerciseInstruction.Prescribed_Date)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            No. of Reps: @item.ExerciseInstruction.Number_Of_Reps<br />
                            No. of Secs to hold: @item.ExerciseInstruction.Number_Of_Secs_PositionHold<br />
                            No. of Sets: @item.ExerciseInstruction.Number_Of_Sets_Per_Day<br />
                            No. of Times: @item.ExerciseInstruction.Frequency_Per_Week<br />
                            Remarks: @if (item.ExerciseInstruction.Remark == null || item.ExerciseInstruction.Remark.Trim() == "")
                        {
                                @:NIL
                                }
                        else
                        {
                                @item.ExerciseInstruction.Remark
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => item.ExerciseInstruction.ToPerform, new { htmlAttributes = new { style = "width:23px; height:23px;" } })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("View", "Details", new { id = Model[j].ExerciseInstruction.ExerciseInstructionID, pageFrom = "performExercises" }, new { target = "_blank" })
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    j++;
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

                @if (Model.Count() != 0)
                {
                    <input type='submit' value='Save and Update' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" />
                }
}
```

The controller that is working on this is as below.

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Therapist")]
        public ActionResult ToPerformExercises(int? pid, List<AssignmentViewModel> avmLIst)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                foreach (var item in avmLIst)
                {

                    ExerciseInstruction eI = db.ExerciseInstructions.SingleOrDefault(a => a.ExerciseInstructionID == item.ExerciseInstruction.ExerciseInstructionID);
                    eI.ToPerform = item.ExerciseInstruction.ToPerform;
                    db.Entry(eI).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("ViewToPerform", "AssignExercisesViewModel", new { pid = pid });
        }
```

This is the submit pop up box

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!— Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Are you sure you want to add/remove the Ongoing Exercise(s) for the patient?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Confirm" onclick="DisableButton(this)" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My problem is very similar to this link [Jquery tool DataTable unable to post/submit in an MVC3 Html.BeginForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066703/jquery-tool-datatable-unable-to-post-submit-in-an-mvc3-html-beginform)
However i am unsure of how he actually solve it as the explanation on his answer was really brief.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: There's a lot of unrelated code here, and the question is missing some critical code.  (Namely the controller action.)  Can you provide a simple and complete example of the problem?  How are you passing values to the controller?  What is actually included in the form post?  What does the controller expect?

Comment: ok updated the question.:D

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot going on here, but I'll take a shot at it based on a common pitfall in model binding... You should change the `foreach` to a `for` loop, then alter your `HtmlEditorFor` calls to use the index.

So to greatly simplify what you have above...

```
for(int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
{
    // other things

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i]. //rest of stuff

    // more other things
```

MVC serializes a name into the element for you, then attempts to re-map this server-side when posting the form. If you use a foreach loop in this way, it will lose the index and fail to bind.

You can see this effect happening if you watch your requests in Fiddler (or Chrome or whatever).

Comment: Hi. I tried to change it to the above code, however the problem still exist. I tried changing 
 Html.DisplayFor
 to Html.TextAreaFor
Some how i am able to get the value of the model.

Comment: @Ugine, can you add your form element or `BeginForm` call to your code sample? I'd like to see the post action associated with the submit button.

Comment: Done. Apparently i am able to pass information over to the controller, however as this page allow user to click on the
@Html.EditorFor(model => item.ExerciseInstruction.ToPerform, new { htmlAttributes = new { style = "width:23px; height:23px;" } })
It does not take the updated information from the data table.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint to the Controller's Post action and inspect the `Request` object. Are you seeing any of your form's values? What do the keys look like?

Comment: There are values in the list (I manage to pass values over now), however it is not the updated information. Because at the end of the day, the therapist will be able to click on the editorFor button. This information need to be captured so that i can submit this to the controller and update it to my data base.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer. They experienced a similar problem when using foreach instead of for. The model binding does not work in the former case.

[Model.List is null on POST using Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159796/model-list-is-null-on-post-using-razor)