# Razor forms with lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

New to MVC and just struggling with retrieving my form data from a List<>. In my controller, I am able to get my Name value (recipe name) correctly but cannot get the Ingredient Name value, always coming back as NULL?

Below are some code snippets from my project.

MODEL

```
public class Recipe
{

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    public Recipe()
    {
        Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>()
        {
            new Ingredient()
        };

    }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

VIEW

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateEdit", "Recipe"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name, "Name")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
        </div>

        <h2>Ingredient(s)</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Ingredients.FirstOrDefault().Name, "Name")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Ingredients.FirstOrDefault().Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" text="submit" />
        </div>
    }
```

CONTROLLER

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEdit(Recipe recipe)
{           
   var recipeName = recipe.Name // <--- Works
   var ingredientName = recipe.Ingredients.FirstOrDefault().Name; //<--- NULL value

   return View(recipe);
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23553225/3585278

Comment: You cannot use `.FirstOrDefault()` in the view - you need to use a `for` loop or custom `EditorTemplate` for `Ingredient` - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943). But if you only want one `Ingredient`, why are you using `List<Ingredient>`?

Comment: @Danieboy thanks that solved my problem

Comment: @StephenMuecke the form will eventually allow the ability to add multiple ingredients to a recipe, that's my next challenge :)

Comment: The read the link I gave you to understand what the html you generate needs to be (and how to achieve it)

Comment: And if you want to dynamically add (and remove) collection items in the view, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)

Answer (score 2):

1. `Ingredients` is a property of class `Recipe` and is of type `List<Ingredient>`.
2. The action to which you are posting CreateEdit has a parameter `Recipe`.

To bind list objects we need to provide an index for each items. Like for example

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/CreateEdit">

    <input type="text" name="recipe.Ingredients[0].Name" value="Red Sauce" />

    <input type="text" name="recipe.Ingredients[1].Name" value="White Sauce" />    

</form>
```

Read this link - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ to understand this better.