# Pass objects from PartialView to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Below is the html for a `View` I am working on. It contains a table that is able to add additional rows as needed. The table is initially filled with a `SalesOrder` object upon returning this particular `View`.

```
@model List<Project.Models.SalesOrder>

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Print", "Project", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SO#</th>
                <th>Cust#</th>
                <th>DC</th>
                <th>Stop</th>
                <th>Addr L1</th>
                <th>Addr L2</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Zip</th>
                <th>Ref 1</th>
                <th>Ref 2</th>
                <th>Pcs</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach (var salesOrder in Model)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_SalesOrderRecord", salesOrder)
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Remove Last Record</button>
        <button style="float: right;" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="print">Print Label(s)</button>
    </div>
}
```

Once the Add button is clicked, the script below is called and a `PartialView` is added within the `foreach` of that table.

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Add", "ProjectController")'; // adjust to suit
$('#add').click(function() {
    $.get(url, function (response) {
        $('<tr />').html(response).appendTo(tableBody);
    });
});
```

Below is the `PartialView`:

```
@model Project.Models.SalesOrder   

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("salesOrderTbl"))
{
    <tr id="addRow" class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SalesOrderId)
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SalesOrderNumber, new {@class="form-control", @style="height: auto; width: 5em;"})</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustId, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Location, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DeliveryCompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressL1, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressL2, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.State, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Zip, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reference1, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Reference2, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Pieces, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height: auto; width: 5em;" })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

The next step I am trying to complete is posting the `SalesOrder` objects to my `ProjectController` by using the Print button.

Below is the `ProjectController` method I am trying to post to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Print(List<SalesOrder> salesOrders)
{
    //do things
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working for me and the `salesOrder` list object is always null. I believe I am misunderstanding how to work with `PartialView` so if somebody can point out where I am going wrong, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Pls check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552931/pass-list-objects-with-mvc-razor). You need to pass a counter of SalesOrder to your partial view so that you could create correct input textboxes names for MVC model binding to work properly.

Comment: Easiest way to understand model binding is to keep the input names as if you are accessing the array objects as in c# like `salesOrders[i].SalesOrderId`

Comment: @User3250 if additional table rows containing my SalesOrder object are being created dynamically, how would that affect the solution you suggested?

Comment: @User3250 if you could provide a more detailed solution, I'd appreciate it. I am not quite sure how to implement the linked answer you provided since they are not using PartialView within their table.

Comment: Adding all the values that you want sent to the controller to  @Html.Hiddenfor worked for me in a similar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partial is using `BeginCollectinItem()` to add a prefix named `"salesOrderTbl"` and in order to bind, the name of the parameter in your POST method must match.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Print(List<SalesOrder> salesOrderTbl)
```

Alternatively, keep the existing method parameter name and change the view code in the partial to

```
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("salesOrders"))
{
    ....
}
```

Note also that your partial is creating a `<tr>` element so you do not need to enclose it within another `<tr>` element in the script you use to dynamically add a new row. It should be just

```
var tableBody = $('#...'); // give your tbody an id
var url = '@Url.Action("Add", "ProjectController")'; // adjust to suit
$('#add').click(function() {
    $.get(url, function (response) {
        $(tableBody').append(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Worked like a charm.